# Reshaping the output of a logistic regression

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have defined a logistic regression model as a network with one layer followed by a sigmoid activation using `tf.layers`. The predictions come out as a 2D tensor of shape `(n,1)`, `n` being the size of the batch. However, in order to calculate the loss function, I need a 1D tensor of shape `n`. Of course I can reshape the tensor (and that's what I currently do), but somehow it feels like there should be something more elegant to do. Is there?

---

Code to reproduce the issue

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((20, 6))
data[:, -1] = data[:, -1] > 0.5

e = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data).batch(2).make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
x, y_ = e[:, :-1], e[:, -1]

y = tf.layers.dense(x, 1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
loss_wrong = - tf.reduce_mean(tf.add(tf.multiply(y_, tf.log(y)), tf.multiply((1. - y_), tf.log(1. - y))))

y2 = tf.reshape(y, [-1])  # ugly reshape I would like to get rid of
loss_correct = - tf.reduce_mean(tf.add(tf.multiply(y_, tf.log(y2)), tf.multiply((1. - y_), tf.log(1. - y2))))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    a, b, b2, lw, lc = sess.run([y_, y, y2, loss_wrong, loss_correct])
    print(a)  # a 1D array with the real labels
    print(b)  # a dangerous array of arrays!
    print(b2)  # notice how nice and flat this is
    print(lw)  # wrong when all labels are not the same
    print(lc)  # correct (can test by hand with the data printed)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `tf.squeeze` ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze)). This removes all axes of size 1. So

```
y2 = tf.squeeze(y)
```

Note however that this can lead to issues if some variable dimension (e.g. batch size) also ever happens to be 1 -- `squeeze` will remove such axes as well (which you probably don't want). You can use

```
y2 = tf.squeeze(y, axis=1)
```

to prevent this (note that this will crash in case axis 1 does not have size 1!).

Interestingly, it seems like `tf.squeeze` will always result in at least a 1d tensor, never a scalar. This is different from the numpy version. I.e.

```
tf.squeeze([[1]]) -> array([1])
np.squeeze([[1]]) -> array(1)
```

Hope this is elegant enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, especially for the difference between tf and np. However, in this case, squeezing seems quite similar to reshaping. Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: I doubt there's much of a difference between the two since both just operate on the tensor's shape. I suppose if you wanted you could also do something like y[:, 0] as an alternative but I personally feel like `squeeze` is the clearest option...